# How to use if exists- if not exists in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to convert if exists statement from SQL-Server to PL/SQL but having an error.

I am trying to check if `NAME_1` doesn't exist in my `table_1`, if they don't exist then I am checking if `COLUMN_NAME='NAME_2'` exist in my `table_1`, if it exist then 
  `insert (NAME_1  and  NAME_2)` into my `table_2`.
Thanks

T-SQL (SQL-Server):

```
IF NOT (EXISTS (SELECT * from table_name_1 where name='NAME_1'))
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_1' AND COLUMN_NAME='NAME_2'))

        EXEC('insert into table_name_1 values (''value1'', (select max(column) from table_2), 20)');
    ELSE
        EXEC('insert into table_name_1 values (''value1'', (select max(column) from table_2))');
END
```

PL/SQL (Oracle):

```
DECLARE
l_count NUMBER;
l_count_2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
select count(*) into l_count from table_1 where name='NAME_1';
IF l_count = 0  then
    BEGIN 
        select count(*) into l_count_2 FROM dba_tab_cols  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_1' AND COLUMN_NAME='NAME_2';

        IF l_count_2 > 0 THEN        
          sql_cnt :=  INSERT INTO table_1  VALUES ('value1', "select max(column) from table_2" , '20' );          
        ELSE             
            sql_cnt:= INSERT INTO table_1  VALUES ('value1', "select max(column) from table_2" );
        END IF;                    
       BEGIN
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_cnt ;
       END;
    END;
END IF;       
END;
```

ERROR

> Error report
>   ORA-06550: line 11, column 27:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT" when expecting one of the

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Your Insert statement have problem of inconsistent values. In 1 statement you have 2 values while in other you have 3. You have to pass consistent values matching with the no of columns in table_1.

Comment: Do you like to insert the **text** `select max(column) from table_2` of the actual max value of column?

Comment: @wernfried it not the text but the actual max date of column.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is mostly good, but you would have to modify it either like this:

```
DECLARE
l_count NUMBER;
l_count_2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
select count(*) into l_count from table_1 where name='NAME_1';
IF l_count = 0  then
    BEGIN 
        select count(*) into l_count_2 FROM dba_tab_cols  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_1' AND COLUMN_NAME='NAME_2';

        IF l_count_2 > 0 THEN        
          sql_cnt :=  'INSERT INTO table_1 (xycolumn1, xycolumn2, xycolumn3) VALUES (''value1'', ''select max(column) from table_2'', ''20'')';          
        ELSE             
           sql_cnt := 'INSERT INTO table_1 (xycolumn1, xycolumn2) VALUES (''value1'', ''select max(column) from table_2'')';
        END IF;                    
       BEGIN
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_cnt ;
       END;
    END;
END IF;       
END;
```

or like this:

```
DECLARE
l_count NUMBER;
l_count_2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
select count(*) into l_count from table_1 where name='NAME_1';
IF l_count = 0  then
    BEGIN 
        select count(*) into l_count_2 FROM dba_tab_cols  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_1' AND COLUMN_NAME='NAME_2';

        IF l_count_2 > 0 THEN        
          INSERT INTO table_1 (xycolumn1, xycolumn2, xycolumn3) VALUES ('value1', 'select max(column) from table_2', '20' );          
        ELSE             
          INSERT INTO table_1 (xycolumn1, xycolumn2) VALUES ('value1', 'select max(column) from table_2');
        END IF;   
    END;
END IF;       
END;
```

The first option is using the correct Oracle spelling for string creations and dynamic SQL and the second option is avoiding dynamic SQL altogether by executing `INSERT` on the spot (the option I prefer).

**EDIT :** The error you got was because you did not encapsulate your `INSERT` inside a string. That is what I changed for you in my first option when I mentioned `correct Oracle spelling for string creations and dynamic SQL`.

I hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks @goran, i have tried to use first solution but the error is : ORA-00947: not enough values at this line : EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_cnt ;                                                    and with the second solution the error is : PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here at this line  :  INSERT INTO table_1  VALUES ('value1', "select max(column) from table_2" , '20' ); ideas plse ?

Comment: It makes the insert statement more robust if the column names are included `INSERT INTO tbl (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)`. Are the double quotes around `select max(column) from table_2` correct? They usually escape identifiers. Use single quotes to delimit strings.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes is correct, you should define precise columns you want those values to be put in and you should put them in the same order as values you're inputting. That wouldn't be required if you're inserting in all the existing columns of your table, but that's obviously not the case here as both times you're inserting in the same table, but once you're inserting 2 columns and the second time 3 columns. I overlooked that, believing you're inserting in different tables and in all of their columns.
Olivier is also correct about strings. I'll edit my post to place a correct example!

Comment: Thank you both it works. but correct the post : in the second INSERT we dont need to add the third column name because we insert just two values. around select max(column) from table_2 , we need to add the ()  to insert the SELECT result in table_1.  thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

Provided `table_2` has no `DEFAULT` value for third column you can do it much simpler like this one:

```
DECLARE
    l_count NUMBER;
    l_count_2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count FROM table_1 WHERE NAME='NAME_1';
    IF l_count = 0  THEN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO l_count_2 FROM dba_tab_cols  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_1' AND COLUMN_NAME='NAME_2';

        INSERT INTO table_1
        SELECT 'value1', MAX(column), CASE WHEN l_count_2 > 0 THEN 20 ELSE NULL end 
        FROM table_2;

    END IF;       
END;
```

There is no reason for dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

*(answer given before the Oracle version and the error message were inserted into the question)*

As you can see here: [IF-THEN-ELSE Statement](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php), the syntax is different for Oracle

```
IF condition THEN
   {...statements to execute when condition is TRUE...}
ELSE
   {...statements to execute when condition is FALSE...}
END IF;
```

I.e., there is no `BEGIN ... END` block. Instead the statement ends with `END IF`

Comment: Sorry I just saw your picture somewhere else and thought you were the OP

Comment: @satcha: Your edit seems to make my answer superfluous.